# Disable Custom Chunk Button calling PSE script if there is no write access to selected item

Tags: powershell-extensions, content-editor, security, role-management

I have a custom Button in the content Editor (Share), basically it just runs a PSE Script that moves final layout to shared layout.
Only a specific role can see the button.
Now my problem is, that the button is enabled even if the user has no write access to the item, and therefore he can run the script.
For the save button etc. it seems to work. Does anyone know what kind of logic determines if the button is enabled or disabled?

How can I disable the button if I click on an Item without write Access?

[image: Button]

Comment: Take a look at this - https://blogs.perficient.com/2015/09/28/hiding-buttons-in-sitecore/#:~:text=Open%20your%20the%20desired%20user,Screenshots)%20and%20deny%20read%20access.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, this would Hide the Button for the Role. Its ok to see the button this works fine, the button should be disabled on items without write access

Comment: Can you add to the question definition of your button from core db? Especially click event

Comment: Apply rules on the items as seen here https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/libraries-and-scripts#rules-usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "normal" buttons not calling SPE script, this is straight forward. In your definition of click event, you hook command. For example for **Display Name** button, **Click** command is **item:setdisplayname** and it's defined like this:

```
   <command name="item:setdisplayname" type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.SetDisplayName,Sitecore.Kernel" />
```

So basically this code is called:

[image]

Mind the QueryState method and how it's setting CommandState.Disabled status when Length of context items doesn't equal 1 (in other words, you do not have write permissions for that context item).

To solve your problem, you can implement something similar logic in your PS script so you won't run the script at the end when same conditions are met.
It won't disable the button but at least it won't run the script when user doesn't have proper permissions.

Comment: Thank you for that clear explanation Peter. My Command is indeed just the trigger of the script: item:executescript(id=$ItemID,script={094BCEF9-26F5-4D1E-B518-E28ED7CF364B},scriptDb=master)

Comment: My pleasure @Bgl86

Answer (score 3):

When working with SPE you can use the rules fields (Show/Enable) to manage the state of the buttons. I use these at work all the time and work reliably.

As you can see in the following figure, the Elevated Unlock feature included with SPE makes use of the rules fields.

[image: Elevated Unlock]

The documentation in the [SPE book outlines](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/libraries-and-scripts#rules-usage) in which scenarios the Show Rule and Enable Rule are used. You can apply the rules at the script and script library levels, depending on your usage.